# Why does jQuery formData need contentType=false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-type, form-data

My question is about sending form data using jQuery. I read that when the contentType line is omitted, jQuery defaults to x-www-formdata-urlencoded encoding. This is what I think SHOULD be used. But if contentType is set to false, it uses multipart/form-data encoding.

However, when contentType is omitted, the PHP says 'searchcity' index is undefined, meaning jQuery didn't successfully send 'searchcity' from my HTML input. When contentType is set to false, that means jQuery uses multipart/form-data, and PHP is able to find the index and everything works fine.

But in HTML, if you omit 'enctype', it defaults to x-www-formdata-urlencoding. If I use `<form action = 'search.php' method = "POST"></form>`, it uses x-www-formdata-urlencoding and works fine. I would NOT need to use `<form action = 'search.php' method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data"></form>`

So how come when sending a form, HTML can send form data successfully to PHP using x-www-formdata-urlencoding, but jQuery requires multipart/form-data?

I am sending only text, no files.

```
<html>
        <header><script src = "/jquery.js"></script></header>
        <a href="/login.html">Login/Register</a> <br>

        <form id = "searchform">
            <input type = "text" name = "searchcity" size = "40"><br>
            <input type = "button" id = "submit" value = "Search">
        </form>

        <script>
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                if( $("#searchform")[0].reportValidity() ){
                    var form = new FormData( $("#searchform")[0] );
                    $.post({
                        url:"/search.php",
                        processData:false,   //prevents jquery from turning form to string
                        contentType:false,   // this means to use multipart form encoding, but why?
                        data:form,
                        success:function(data){
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        </script>
        </html>
```

```
https://pastebin.com/rMh3dr7r
```

Comment: `When contentType is set to false, that means jQuery uses multipart/form-data`. Not true, read the docs: `As of jQuery 1.6 you can pass false to tell jQuery to not set any content type header.` https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ (under *contentType*)

Comment: I see, but if so, how come HTML can still send the form via x-www-formdata-urlencoding, but jQuery needs a contentType:false? By default, if contentType is omitted, jQuery sends by x-www-formdata-urlencoding.

Answer (score 1):

contentType option to false is used for multipart/form-data forms that pass files. When one sets the contentType option to false, it forces jQuery not to add a Content-Type header, otherwise, the boundary string will be missing from it.

Comment: I see, but if so, how come HTML can still send the form via x-www-formdata-urlencoding, but jQuery needs a contentType:false? By default, if contentType is omitted, jQuery sends by x-www-formdata-urlencoding.